# Calculate more time points from ode() of the "deSolve" R package without increasing runtime

Tags: r, performance, ode

I wrote a function: *ODEsystem = function(t, states, parameters)*, which contains an ODE-system  and solved it with the well documented R packages "deSolve" written by Karline Soetaert, Thomas Petzoldt and R. Woodrow Setzer. The documentation of the package is comprehensive and with many examples. It gives me confidence in their programming and memory optimization skills.

However, when solving the ODE-system with daily intervals instead of monthly intervals the time it takes to calculate the state-values for the specified moments increases tenfold. There might be a bit additional calculations for reaching the exact required moments in time, but for both cases roughly the same internal dynamic time steps should have been made. I did not expect such a large drop in runtime.

The call to *ode()* in “desolve” looks like this:

```
out <- as.data.frame(ode(states, t=times, func=ODEsystem), parms=parameters, method="ode45"))
```

I used two variants for times
    times = seq(0, 100*365, by=365/12)  # 100 years, one time point per month
    times = seq(0, 100*365, by=1)  # 100 years, one time point per day

Calling with data points per month

```
user  system elapsed 
4.59    0.00    4.58
```

Calling with data points per month and *cmpfun()* on the function containing the ODEsystem

```
user  system elapsed 
4.39    0.00    4.38
```

Calling with data points per day

```
user  system elapsed 
44.41    0.00   44.46
```

Calling with data points per day and *cmpfun()*  on the function containing the ODEsystem

```
user  system elapsed 
43.01    0.00   43.17
```

The runtime measured with *system.time()* increases with factor ten when switching from monthly intervals to daily intervals. Matters do not improve much by using *cmpfun()* on the function containing the ODE-system.

(The output "out" is only assigned when the function call to *ode()* is done. Thus pre-assigning "out" yields no performance gain.)

**Question 1:** I am looking for the reason why there is this decrease in runtime/performance.

(I expect it to be in the internals of the deSolve package.)

**Question 2:** Given the answer to Question 1, how can I improve the runtime without resorting to dynamic link libraries?

Pre-assign some memory for what will become “out” might help (using knowledge on the time steps in “times”), but I do not known which internal variable in *ode()* to affect.

```
    #### Clear currrent lists from memory
    rm(list=ls())

    ### Load libraries
    # library(rootSolve);library(ggplot2);
    library(base);library(deSolve);library(stringr);library(compiler);library(data.table);

    #### constants
    dpy=365;durX1 = 40*dpy;rH = 1/durX1;durX4 = 365/12;rX4 = 1/durX4;durX6 = 365/12;rX6 = 1/durX6;durX2 = 80;rX2 = 1/durX2;durX3 = 31;rX3 = 1/durX3;durX7 = 20*365/12;rX7 = 1/durX7;durX5 = 29;rX5 = 1/durX5;durX8 = 200;rX8 = 1/durX8;fS = 0.013;fR = 8/100;fL = .03;fP = .03;fF = .05;X1zero = 1000;UDdur = 365/12*5;rK = rX3*(1/UDdur);fD1 = .05;fD2 = .05;durbt = 4;bt = 1/durbt;LX11 = 14;rF = 1/LX11;durX11 = 5;rX11 = 1/durX11;iniX12 = 0;pH = 1;frac_Im = 0;durX9 = dpy*5;ini_X2 = 1;sp = .90;fpX1 = 5;NF = fpX1*X1zero;rT1 = fD1*rX4;rT2 = fD2*rX6;pX1 = 0*sp;pX2 = 1/80*sp;pX3 = .50*sp;pX4 = .5*sp;pX6 = .5*sp;pX7 = 1/100*sp;pX5 = pX3;pX9 = 0*sp;pX8 = 1*sp;rX9 = 1/durX9;

    #### vector with parameters
    parameters = c(rH, rX3, rX4, rX6, rX2, rX8, rX7, rX5, rK, rT1, rT2, bt, rF, NF, rX11, pX1, pX2, pX3, pX4, pX6, pX7, pX5, pX9, pX8, rX9, X1zero)

    ### States contains initial conditions 
    states = c( X1 =X1zero-1,X2=1,X3=0, X4=0, X5=0,X6=0, X7=0, X8=0, X9=0, X10=NF,X11=0,X12=0, X13 = 0)

    ### function with ODE system
    ODEsystem = function(t,states,parameters){
      with(as.list(c(states,parameters)),{
        ### functions
        X1part = (pX2*X2 + pX3*X3 + pX4*X4 + pX6*X6 + pX7*X7 + pX5*X5 + pX9*X9 + pX8*X8); prob1 = bt * X12 / X1zero; lF = bt * X1part/X1zero; AD = rK*(X3+X5+X4+X6)+rT1*X4+rT2*X6;
        ### fluxes
        J1 = prob1*X1; J2 = fS*rX2*X2; J3 = (1-fS)*rX2*X2; J4 = (1-fP)*rX3*X3 ; J5 = fP*rX3*X3; J6 = (1-fF)*rX4*X4; J7 = fF*rX4*X4; J8 = rX6*X6; J9 = fR*rX7*X7; J10 = rX5*X5; J11 = (1-fR)*(1-fL)*rX7*X7; J12 = (1-fR)*fL*rX7*X7; J13 = rX8*X8; J14 = rH*X3; J15 = rH*X1; J16 = rH*X2; J17 = rH*X4; J18 = rH*X6; J19 = rH*X5; J20 = rH*X8; J21 = rH*X7; J22 = rH*X9; J23 = rK*X3; J24 = rK*X4; J25 = rK*X6; J26 = rT2*X6; J27 = rH*X1zero; J28 = rT1*X4; J29 = AD; J30 = rK*X5; J31 = rF*X12; J32 = rF*X11; J33 = rF*X10; J34 = lF*X10; J35 = rX11*X11; J36 = rF*NF; J37 = rX9*X9; J38 = 0; J39 = 0; J40 = 0; J41 = 0; J42 = 0; J43 = 0; flux1=J4/X1zero*1e4*dpy; flux2=J12/X1zero*1e4*dpy;

        # rate of change    
        dX1 = - J1 - J15 + J27 + J29 + J37
        dX2 = + J1 - J2 - J3 - J16 - J40
        dX3 = + J2 - J4 - J5 - J14 - J23 - J41
        dX4 = + J4 - J6 - J7 - J17 - J24 - J28
        dX5 = + J9 - J10 - J19 - J30 - J43
        dX6 = + J7 - J8 + J10 - J18 - J25 - J26
        dX7 = + J5 + J6 + J8 - J9 - J11 - J12 - J21
        dX8 = + J12 - J13 - J20 - J42   
        dX9 = + J3 + J11 + J13 - J22 - J37 + J40 + J41 + J42 + J43
        dX10 = - J33 - J34 + J36
        dX11 = - J32 + J34 - J35
        dX12 = - J31 + J35
        dX13 = + J38 - J39

        # return the rate of change
                list(c(dX1,dX2,dX3,dX4,dX5,dX6,dX7,dX8,dX9,dX10,dX11,dX12,dX13),flux1,flux2,prob1)
      })
    }

    ## compiled version of ODE system function
    cfODEsystem=cmpfun(ODEsystem)

    #### time points to be calculated
    times = seq(0, 100*365,by=365/12) # 100 year, time points per month
    #times = seq(0, 100*365,by=1) # 100 year, time points per day

    ### calculations
    system.time(out <- as.data.frame(ode(states, t=times, func=ODEsystem, parms=parameters, method="ode45")))
    #system.time(out <- as.data.frame(ode(states, t=times, func=cfODEsystem, parms=parameters, method="ode45")))

    ### longitudinal plots of each variable, flux1 and 2 and prob1
    for (i in seq(from=2, to=dim(out)[2], by=1) ) { 
        tempdata <- out[c("time",names(out)[i])]
        tempdata$time= tempdata$time/365
        templabel <-names(out)[i]
        plot(tempdata,col = "black","l",xlab="time (years)",ylab=templabel,
     xlim=c(0, max(tempdata$time)), ylim=c(0, signif(max(tempdata[2]),2)))
    }
```

Comment: is there any chance of a reproducible example?

Comment: Dear Ben Bolker, I added the code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks for writing this question, it prompted me to look into the deSolve internals and learn a bit (and also maybe speed my own code up).

**Question 1**

The ODE function is called a number of times to solve the function (maybe less than the number of timepoints), but then is also called once a timepoint to evaluate the additional algebraic equations.  So if you add 30x the timepoints, you will always add to the runtime but by less than a factor of 30, due to things like setup and teardown.

**Question 2**

There are a few things you can do to speed things up without resorting to C code (though that is an excellent option)

1. Use a different solver (e.g. lsoda, which on my system is around 5x faster than ode45)
2. When using lsoda, increase the hmax to allow the adaptive timestepping more freedom to integrate ahead (another speedup)
3. rewrite the code to avoid the use of `with`, instead using array accesses (possibly to temporary named variables).